# How do I create a table with the primary keys of 2 other tables in symfony2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, symfony

I have such a scenario that I have 2 tables and want to create a 3rd table whose columns are ONLY the 2 primary keys of the 2 tables. The 2 tables are :-

```
Events.php
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="institute_event_details")
 */

class Events
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $eid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="eventname",type="string", length=50)
 */
protected $eventname;

public function getEId() {
    return $this->eid;
}

public function getEventname()
{
    return $this->eventname;
}

public function setEventname($eventname)
{
    $this->eventname = $eventname;

    return $this;
}

}
```

AND

Student.php

```
namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="institute_student_details")
 */
class Student extends BaseUser
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $uid;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="firstname",type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\NotBlank(),
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 3,
 *      max = 100,
 *      minMessage = "Your name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Your name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/\d/",
 *     match=false,
 *     message="Your name cannot contain a number")
 */
protected $firstname;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="lastname",type="string", length=50)
 * @Assert\Length(
 *      min = 3,
 *      max = 100,
 *      minMessage = "Your name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long",
 *      maxMessage = "Your name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters long")
 * @Assert\Regex(
 *     pattern="/\d/",
 *     match=false,
 *     message="Your name cannot contain a number")
 */
protected $lastname;

/**
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @Assert\Email()
 * 
 */
protected $email;

/**
 * Plain password. Used for model validation. Must not be persisted.
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * 
 */
protected $plainPassword;

public function getFirstname()
{
    return $this->firstname;
}

public function getLastname()
{
    return $this->lastname;
}

public function setFirstname($firstname)
{
    $this->firstname = $firstname;

    return $this;
}

public function setLastname($lastname)
{
    $this->lastname = $lastname;

    return $this;
}

function getEmail() {
    return $this->email;
}

function getPlainPassword() {
    return $this->plainPassword;
}

function setEmail($email) {
    $this->email = $email;
}

function setPlainPassword($plainPassword) {
    $this->plainPassword = $plainPassword;
}

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    // your own logic
}
}
```

Now, I want to create a new table,"Subscription" whose columns are only "uid" and "eid", in the database. Now many "Student" can register for many "Events" . What is the relationship between these tables and where do I specify these:-

Subscription.php

```
<?php

namespace InstituteEvents\StudentBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="institute_subscription_details")
 */

class Subscription
{

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $uid;

/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
protected $eid;

 public function getUId() {
    return $this->uid;
}

 public function getEId() {
    return $this->eid;
}
}
```

How do I create these tables in the database and what is the relationship between these tables with the condition that :- Many "Student" can register for many "Events" AND Many "Events" can have many "Student" ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you need additional entity. DoctrineORM provides many-to-many bidirectional relations.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Comment: Because my requirement is that we create a third table

Comment: Many to Many relations creates third table to store relations (there is no other way to implement it). What's the problem?

Comment: Thank You for your help, time and the link. It worked. I still can't vote up for the answer, else I would have

Comment: @sachintendulkar you can place a check mark in front of the answer if you want to accept it.

Comment: Yup, forgot. It's ticked now. Thank you